# How can a regular user be notified of a required reboot?

Tags: 14.04, updates, reboot

I am administrating multiple machines on which I am admin and the users have not admin-rights. The machines are configured to pull and install updates automatically. A new kernel will require a reboot. On Ubuntu Precise this was made visible to the user through the color change of the shutdown-menu in the upper right corner (it turned red). Now, on Ubuntu Trusty, there is not color change anymore. Also, the Update Manager will not pop up for regular users reminding them of an outstanding reboot.

How can a regular user know that a reboot is required?